# Clilcking on a button is giving a Bad Path error

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I'm trying to make a pen which incorporates the javascript exercises I'm learning. Here is the Pen: https://codepen.io/ychalfari/pen/JVYoNW

In this specific case I'm trying to accept an array from an input and run a function which sums the array when you click the button, and the result should show underneath.

When I click the button I either get an Error: "Bad Path /boomboom/index.html"

or nothing happens the page just kind of reloads and it takes me to the top of the page.

The HTML

```
<form id="sum-arr-form"> 
  <div class="form-wrap" >
    <label for="arr-to-sum"> Enter an Array to sum: <input id="arr-to-sum" class ="med-input" type="text" value = ""> 
<button class="btn1" onclick ="sumOfArray()">submit</div> </form>
      <p>Result: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

The Javascript

```
let inputArr = document.getElementById('arr-to-sum').value;
const add = (a,b) => a+b;
const sumOfArray = function() {
  let sum = inputArr.reduce(add);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code.(button tag without type will trigger submit)

```
<button class="btn1" onclick ="sumOfArray()">submit
```

change this line to

```
<input type="button "class="btn1" onclick ="sumOfArray()" value="submit">
```

then get the value of input inside your sumOfArray function. (add the below 2 lines in your sumOfArray function) (waynelpu's answer above)

```
 let inputArrStr = document.getElementById('arr-to-sum').value;
 let inputArr = JSON.parse(inputArrStr);
```

Comment: For some reason when I remove the Submit text (which is outside the button element) and put value="submit", the button is just empty, its weird. Probably something in the css but either way shouldn't affect the functionality right?

Comment: or else use like <button type="button" class="btn1" onclick ="sumOfArray()">submit.
fuctionalities will not be affected

Comment: you haven't added type="button" in your pen

Comment: Savior. Why does adding type="button" make it not refresh and bug out? I mean what was it trying to do before as opposed to after adding type="button"

Comment: button tag without type will trigger submit

Answer (score 1):

The value get from input is string, if you want to process it as array you need to convert to correct type in js, try

```
let inputArrStr = document.getElementById('arr-to-sum').value;
let inputArr = JSON.parse(inputArrStr);
```